# Create hierarchy structure in Android

Tags: android

I have been tasked to create/generate a hierarchy structure with data from SQLite in Android. I am a newbie in Android. Any help will be appreciated.

For example, the hierarchy will be based on Roles. The top level will be the highest privilege, e.g. Admin.

[image]
<sub>(source: [android-advice.com](http://www.android-advice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/org-chart2.dia_.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just extend `View` class, override `onDraw` method and use `Canvas` primitives to draw your structure.